# Getting Overlapping error in COBOL program

Tags: cobol, mainframe, zos, gnucobol, cics

**Cobol program :**

```
PROGRAM-ID. SCHPROG.            
ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.           
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.           
FILE-CONTROL.                   
    SELECT MYFILE ASSIGN TO INDD
    ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL  
    ACCESS MODE IS SEQUENTIAL.  
DATA DIVISION.                  
FILE SECTION.                   
FD MYFILE.                      
01 FILERECORDS.                 
    05 NAME    PIC A(10).       
    05 CLASS-IN PIC 9(1).       
    05 ROLL    PIC 9(5).        
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.        
COPY SCHMAPA.                   
COPY SCHMAPB.                   
COPY SCHMAPC.                   
01 END-OF-FILE PIC A(3) VALUE 'NO'.
PROCEDURE DIVISION.                
000-MAIN-PARA.                     
    PERFORM 100-SEND-MAPA.         
    PERFORM 100-RECEIVE-MAPA.      
    IF CHOICEI = '1'               
    PERFORM 200-SEND-MAPB          
    PERFORM 200-RECEIVE-MAPB       
    PERFORM 200-SEND-MAPB          
    PERFORM 100-SEND-MAPA          
    END-IF.                        
    IF CHOICEI = '2'               
    PERFORM 300-SEND-MAPC          
    PERFORM 300-RECEIVE-MAPC       
    PERFORM 500-SRCH-REC           
    PERFORM 300-SEND-MAPC          
        PERFORM 100-SEND-MAPA              
    END-IF.                            
    STOP RUN.                          
100-SEND-MAPA.                         
    EXEC CICS                          
    SEND                               
    MAP('SCHOLA') MAPSET('SCHMAPA')    
    ERASE                              
    END-EXEC.                          
100-RECEIVE-MAPA.                      
    EXEC CICS                          
    RECEIVE                            
    MAP('SCHOLA') MAPSET('SCHMAPA')    
    END-EXEC.                          
200-SEND-MAPB.                         
    EXEC CICS                          
    SEND                               
         MAP('SCHOLB') MAPSET('SCHMAPB')     
     ERASE                               
     END-EXEC.                           
 200-RECEIVE-MAPB.                       
     EXEC CICS                           
     RECEIVE                             
     MAP('SCHOLB') MAPSET('SCHMAPB')     
     END-EXEC.                           
     PERFORM 400-FILE-PROCESS.           
 300-SEND-MAPC.                          
     EXEC CICS                           
     SEND                                
     MAP('SCHOLC') MAPSET('SCHMAPC')     
     ERASE                               
     END-EXEC.                           
 300-RECEIVE-MAPC.                       
     EXEC CICS                           
         RECEIVE                            
    MAP('SCHOLC') MAPSET('SCHMAPC')    
    END-EXEC.                          
400-FILE-PROCESS.                      
    OPEN OUTPUT MYFILE.                
    MOVE NAMEI TO NAME.                
    MOVE CLASSI TO CLASS-IN.           
    MOVE ROLLI TO ROLL.                
    WRITE FILERECORDS.                 
    CLOSE MYFILE.                      
    MOVE 'RECORD INSERTED' TO MSGBO.   
500-SRCH-REC.                          
    OPEN INPUT MYFILE.                 
    PERFORM UNTIL END-OF-FILE = 'YES'  
         READ MYFILE INTO FILERECORDS 
       AT END                     
        MOVE 'YES' TO END-OF-FILE 
       NOT AT END                 
        IF ROLL =  ROLLCI         
        MOVE NAME TO NAMECO       
        MOVE CLASS-IN TO CLASSCO  
        END-IF                    
     END-READ                     
  END-PERFORM.                    
  CLOSE MYFILE.
```

**Getting error.**

```
IGYPA3043-E   Data-item "FILERECORDS (GROUP)" and record "FILERECORDS (GROUP)"
had overlapping storage.  Movement of data may not occur at execution time.
```

I have provided my cobol program. please check and help me to find the issue.

I am updating file from Cics region and using the same file to get the details and put in cics region.

Not sure why I am getting this error.
Earlier I am using same Group data Item to add record to file and it is working fine.
Please help !!

Comment: Can you share more of the FILE-CONTROL and WORKING STORAGE definitions ?   Where is ROLLCI and NAMECO defined and what do they look like?

Answer (score 5):

While the other answers correctly answer your question, compiling for CICS entails some restrictions documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=cics-coding-cobol-programs-run-under) and quoted as of 06-Apr-2021 below.  You may also want to consult the [CICS documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts) for your version and release of CICS.

> Restriction: You cannot run COBOL programs that have object-oriented
> syntax for Java™ interoperability in CICS. In addition, if you write
> programs to run under CICS, do not use the following code:
>
> - FILE-CONTROL entry in the ENVIRONMENT DIVISION, unless the
>   FILE-CONTROL entry is used for a SORT statement
> - FILE SECTION of the
>   DATA DIVISION, unless the FILE SECTION is used for a SORT statement
> - User-specified parameters to the main program USE declaratives (except
>   USE FOR DEBUGGING)
> - These COBOL language statements:
> - ACCEPT format 1:
>   data transfer (you can use format-2 ACCEPT to retrieve the system date
>   and time)
> - CLOSE
> - DELETE
> - DISPLAY UPON CONSOLE
> - DISPLAY UPON SYSPUNCH
> - MERGE
> - OPEN
> - READ
> - RERUN
> - REWRITE
> - START
> - STOP literal
> - WRITE

[...]

> **Coding file input and output**: You must use CICS commands for most input and output processing. Therefore, do not describe files or code
> any OPEN, CLOSE, READ, START, REWRITE, WRITE, or DELETE statements.
> Instead, use CICS commands to retrieve, update, insert, and delete
> data.

Comment: Good catch @cshneid

Answer (score 3):

`READ MYFILE INTO FILERECORDS` is a duplicate because those are already assigned to each other.
To fix that simply use `READ MYFILE` (the `INTO somewhere` would only be used if you don't want to place that into `FILERECORDS` but somewhere else).

Answer (score 3):

Similar answer to @simon's.

`READ` already places the record into the 01 definition in `MYFILE`.  `READ INTO` is used when you want the data to be placed in another area in `WORKING-STORAGE`.   Executing a `READ INTO` to the `FD` area is simply moving the data over itself.

I was always taught to do a `READ INTO` an area that I defined or was a `COPYBOOK` in `WORKING-STORAGE` to separate the I/O area from the data manipulation.

In assembler what you are doing with `READ` is the equivalent of a `GET LOCATE` as opposed to a `GET MOVE` type of operation.