# CICS Transaction failed with abend U4038

Tags: cobol, mainframe, jcl, cics

This is CICS COBOL Program :-

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.            
PROGRAM-ID. ELECPRG.                
ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.               
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.               
  FILE-CONTROL.                     
    SELECT INFL ASSIGN TO INFLDD    
    ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL 
    ACCESS MODE IS SEQUENTIAL       
    FILE STATUS IS FS.              
DATA DIVISION.                      
FILE SECTION.                       
FD INFL.                            
01 ELEC-REC.                        
    05 P-NUM PIC X(5).              
    05 FILLER PIC X(1).             
    05 C-NAME PIC X(10).            
         05 FILLER PIC X(1).                           
     05 C-UNIT PIC X(4).                           
 WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                          
   COPY ELECMAP.                                   
   01 WS-MSG PIC X(20) VALUE 'BILL PROD DB UPDATE'.
   01 FS     PIC 9(2).                             
 PROCEDURE DIVISION.                               
 000-MAIN.                                         
     MOVE LOW-VALUES TO ELBILLI, ELBILLO           
     PERFORM 100-SEND-MAP.                         
     PERFORM 200-RECEIVE-MAP.                      
     PERFORM PROCESS-DATA.                         
     PERFORM FILE-FUNC.                            
     PERFORM 100-SEND-MAP.                         
     PERFORM 300-RETURN.                           
     STOP RUN.                                     
 100-SEND-MAP.                                     
     EXEC CICS         
     SEND                                 
     MAP('ELBILL') MAPSET('ELECMAP')      
     ERASE                                
     END-EXEC.                            
 200-RECEIVE-MAP.                         
     EXEC CICS                            
     RECEIVE                              
     MAP('ELBILL') MAPSET('ELECMAP')      
     END-EXEC.                            
 PROCESS-DATA.                            
     MOVE CUSNOI TO CUSNOO.               
     MOVE NAMEI TO NAMEO.                 
     MOVE UNITSI TO UNITSO.               
     MOVE UNITSI TO BILLO.                
     MOVE WS-MSG TO MSGO.                 
 FILE-FUNC.                               
     OPEN OUTPUT INFL.                    
     DISPLAY 'OPEN FILE STATUS IS' FS.   
     MOVE CUSNOI TO P-NUM.               
     MOVE NAMEI TO C-NAME.               
     MOVE UNITSI TO C-UNIT.              
     WRITE ELEC-REC.                     
     DISPLAY 'WRITE FILE STATUS IS' FS.  
     CLOSE INFL.                         
     DISPLAY 'CLOSE FILE STATUS IS' FS.  
 300-RETURN.                             
     EXEC CICS                           
     RETURN                              
     END-EXEC.
```

Mine compile jcl :-

```
//CICSCOB JOB CLASS=A,MSGCLASS=A,NOTIFY=&SYSUID,MSGLEVEL=(1,1)  
//PROCLIB JCLLIB ORDER=DFH320.CICS.SDFHPROC                     
//STEP01 EXEC PROC=DFHYITVL,                                    
//            INDEX='DFH320.CICS',                              
//            AD370HLQ='IGY410',                                
//            LE370HLQ='CEE',                                   
//            PROGLIB='DFH320.CICS.SDFHLOAD',                   
//            DSCTLIB='DFH320.CICS.SDFHMAC'                     
//TRN.SYSIN DD DISP=SHR,DSN=RAHUL.COBOL.PROGRAM(ELECPRG)        
//INFLDD DD DSN=RAHUL.CICS.OUTPUT,DISP=SHR                      
//LKED.SYSIN DD *                                               
       NAME ELECPRG(R)                                          
/*
```

Compilation complete a condition code = 0004 , few warnings.
But when I execute the transaction in CICS it terminates with CICS Transaction ELEC failed with abend U4038.

I don't understand the nature of this abend. I just want to update dataset RAHUL.CICS.OUTPUT from my CICS screen input. provided the output file location. Without the file use program is working fine , no abend occurs.

Comment: George's comments are correct and you need to use equivalent EXEC CICS READ commands and define your file via an File Control Table (FCT) entry.  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.3?topic=summary-read provides an overview.  Also, it looks like your using CICS 3.2 ?  is that the correct version ?

Finally, U4038 is a generic abend, there should be other messages that are related that would give you more specifics about the failure.  This is for future reference should you run into this abend again.

Answer (score 3):

This program is a combination of COBOL file control commands and CICS SEND / RECEIVE MAP commands. COBOL file commands such as OPEN, READ,  WRITE and CLOSE are not supported in a CICS transaction.
In a CICS program you have to use the CICS API  as documented here https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.5?topic=programs-understanding-file-control

Comment: By the way a very similar question was asked and answered in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66970097/getting-overlapping-error-in-cobol-program in 2021 - the rules have not changed

Comment: Hi George, thanks. Is there any other way to update data in file from cics?

Comment: No, you have to use the CICS API